# Contract inheritance

Tags: solidity, remix, inheritance, constructor

I really hope this is not a dumb question.

I am trying to call the constructors of the inherited contracts in a structure like this:

```
contract A{
    uint a;

    constructor (uint _a) public {
        a = _a;
    }
}

contract B is A{
    uint b;

    constructor (uint _a, uint _b) public{
        A(_a);
        b = _b;
    }
}

contract C is B{
    uint c;

    constructor(uint _a, uint _b, uint _c) public {
        B(_a, _b);
        c = _c;
    }
}
```

If I try to compile it in Remix I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Exactly one argument expected for explicit type conversion B(_a, _b);
```

Why can't I call the constructor of B with two variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this exact scenario is covered by the Solidity: [Inheritance > Arguments for Base Constructors](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors)

Here is the example they give:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract Base {
    uint x;
    constructor(uint _x) public { x = _x; }
}

contract Derived2 is Base {
    constructor(uint _y) Base(_y * _y) public {}
}
```

So for you, it would look something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract A{
    uint a;

    constructor (uint _a) public {
        a = _a;
    }
}

contract B is A{
    uint b;

    constructor (uint _a, uint _b) A(_a) public{
        b = _b;
    }
}

contract C is B{
    uint c;

    constructor(uint _a, uint _b, uint _c) B(_a, _b) public {
        c = _c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer by @shawn-tabrizi is a good example of how to set up inheritance properly but the reason you got the error is different and I want to share for anyone else that finds this answer for the same error message.

The problem is that you didn't use **`new`** before calling the constructor for `B`.  That wouldn't have made the inheritance work but it's the reason for that error message.

Comment: What is the advantage of setting up things in the way that Shawn has over just using `new`?

Comment: Shawn showed an example with proper inheritance. Adding in `new` will not make inheritance work. The error is because `B(_a, _b)` was called without `new`.

Comment: Blessed be your answer :)